# How to download snapshot for Operations in Azure AppInsight

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

Is there a way to download debug snapshots for Operations in Azure App Insight. (It can be done for the exception) Need to use these to debug Asp. Net core project in VS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the azure portal admin needs to create a new role and assign a user to see and download snapshots from [App Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/snapshot-debugger).